# compute $\nabla f$ for a function over a cone

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Let $D$ be the cone $D=\{rt:r>0, t\in\Omega\}$ with $\Omega\subset S^{n-1}$.

I want to show that
$$
\frac1{r^2}\int_{B_r}\frac{|\nabla f(x)|^2}{|x|^{n-2}} dx= C(n,g)r^{2(a-1)}
$$
where $C(n,g)$ is a constant depending on $n$ and $g$, for a function $f(x)=r^ag(x)$ on $D$ where $g$ is harmonic and homogeneous.

So how do you calculate $\nabla f$?

Add: We extend $f$ by zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch to radial coordinates $( f(x) = R^a g(r,\theta) )$(fixing $R$ as the radius of the ball and $r$ as the radial variable) we see that
$$ \nabla f(x)  = R^a \nabla g(r,\theta) $$ Thus we have
$$ \frac{1}{R^2} \int_{B_R} \frac{ | \nabla f|^2}{|x|^{n-2} } dx = \underbrace{\frac{R^{2a}}{R^2}}_{R^{2(a-1)}} \underbrace{\int_{S^{n-1}} \int_0^R \frac{ | \nabla g |^2}{r^{n-2}} r^{n-1}dr d \Omega }_{=C(n,g)} = C(n,g) R^{2(a-1)}$$
as you see, we don't really need to compute the gradient. But since $g$ is harmonic, we know the integral converges to some constant.